# can't correctly MATCH nodes based on property array length

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a DB consisting of Nodes with only one Label.
The Node's properties contain, among other things, a variable length string array.

Let's say, the Nodes look like this:

```
{
  "array": ["str1","str2"],
  "key1": "whatever",
  "key2": "dummy"
}
```

Most of the time, but not always, the array's length is 0.
I'm trying to write a Cypher query that would return only those Nodes with a non-zero length array.

IMO, such a query should look like this:

```
MATCH (n:mylabel)
WHERE size(n.array)>0
RETURN n
```

However, when I run it (through web interface), the DB returns ALL nodes, including those with a zero-length array.

I did suspect for a while that I'm using the size() function incorrectly. However, when I put

```
MATCH (n:mylabel)
RETURN size(n.array)
```

the system does return the correct array lengths.

Please advise.

Comment: Your query is good, and I have done a little test on my laptop, and just it works as expected. Which version of Neo4j  are you using ?

Comment: Ah, interesting. Community 3.4.7 under Linux.

Comment: @vanhemt Can you give an example of a query to add data on which we can check this behavior?

Comment: @stdob I can't reproduce the problem with the original dataset after rebooting/reloading the data. However, it is exactly the same dataset, loaded with a script.